# Automating dto translations

Tags: c#, resharper, code-duplication

In our architecture there are multiple layers and they speak different DTOs, so it common to translate objects with exactly the same properties.

What are the tools/techniques available which help with the laborious task of creating class `A` which looks like class `B` and objects of class `A` are created from objects of class `B`?

I'm after solutions which would allow me to generate this translating code. Keeping two objects always in sync is another issue :)

I have a Resharper license.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AutoMapper is exactly what you want.](http://automapper.org/)

It allows you to setup mapping profiles that map between objects with similar/same properties.